# Using Axios to write to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I'm using nuxtjs/axios and Mongoose to write to MongoDB. The POST always works but it takes a few seconds for the insert to get into MongoDB. Problem is that I'm trying to call a GET immediately after a new POST so i can get all the latest records. That doesn't always happen because it takes a few seconds for the data to get into the DB. Here's my *index.js* file for the server:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
require('dotenv').config();
}
const Post = require('./models/post');
const express = require('express');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const xss = require('xss-clean');


app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    })
  )
app.use(express.json())
app.use(xss());

const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');
config.dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
const { host, port } = nuxt.options.server;

const username = process.env.username;
const pwd = process.env.pwd;
const server = process.env.server;
const db = process.env.db;

const dbURI = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${pwd}@${server}/${db}? 
   retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

async function start() {
    if (config.dev) {
        const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
        await builder.build();
    } else {
        await nuxt.ready();
    }
    app.use(nuxt.render);
}

start();

mongoose
    .connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then((result) => {
        app.listen(port, host); // listen
        }
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
    Post
        .find()
        .sort({createdAt: -1})
        .then((result) => {
            res.send(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
})

app.post(
    '/posts', 
    (req, res) => {
        const post = new Post({
            body: req.body.post.trim()
        });
        post
            .save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result);
            })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
);
```

I feel like in *app.post* the *.save()* isn't waiting for the insert to complete. Is my implementation wrong? Here's my Store:

```
export const actions = {
    async getPosts() {
        let res = await this.$axios.get(`/posts`);
        return res;
    }
}

export const mutations = {
    async savePost(state, data) {
        let res = await this.$axios.post('/posts', {post: data});
        return res;
    } 
}
```

And here's my *index.vue* file:

```
export default {
  components: {},
  data: () => ({
    posts:[],
    confession: ""
  }),
  mounted(){
    this.getPosts();
  },
  methods: {
    async getPosts() {
      let res = await this.$store.dispatch('getPosts');
      this.posts = res;
    },
    async savePost(payload) {
      let res = await this.$store.commit('savePost', payload);
      return res;
    },
    clear(){
      this.confession = "";
    },
    focusInput() {
      this.$refs.confession.focus();
    },
    onSubmit() {
      this
        .savePost(this.confession.trim())
        .then((result) => {
          this.playSound(); 
          this.getPosts();
          this.clear();
          this.focusInput();
        });
    },
    playSound: function(){
        // sound code
    }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add **w: "majority"** option in save method.
[Mongoose Documentation of save options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-save)
[MongoDB Documentation for further explanation of 'writeConcern'](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/write-concern/)

```
app.post(
    '/posts', 
    (req, res) => {
        const post = new Post({
            body: req.body.post.trim()
        });
        post
            .save({w: "majority"})
            .then((result) => {
                res.send(result);
            })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
);
```